# Python Calculation by group

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a data:

```
print(dataset)
variable   groups    value  
    Both        I  3099060    
    Both        U   175820    
    C_only      I  5207055    
    C_only      U   225992    
    P_only      I  4063438    
    P_only      U   175593    
      None      I  9413116    
      None      U   292982    

dataset.value.dtype
dtype('int64')
type(dataset)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

I am trying to create a new variable, called `value2`, which is calculated by value divided by the total of value under each group.
What I want:

```
variable   groups    value     value2
    Both        I  3099060    0.14227
    Both        U   175820    0.20200
    C_only      I  5207055    0.23905
    C_only      U   225992    0.25965
    P_only      I  4063438    0.18654
    P_only      U   175593    0.20174
      None      I  9413116    0.43214
      None      U   292982    0.33661
```

I used `groupby` to calculate but get `NaN`:

```
dataset['value2'] = dataset.groupby(['groups']).value / dataset.groupby(['groups']).value.sum()
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is None a string or is it the python built-in `None`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` + [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) to create an array same shape as your `values` column, this way you can simply divide both:

```
df['value2'] = df['value'] / df.groupby('groups')['value'].transform('sum')
```

**Or**

We can use the [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) method

```
df['value2'] = df['value'].div(df.groupby('groups')['value'].transform('sum'))
```

---

```
  variable groups    value    value2
0     Both      I  3099060  0.142272
1     Both      U   175820  0.202002
2   C_only      I  5207055  0.239046
3   C_only      U   225992  0.259645
4   P_only      I  4063438  0.186545
5   P_only      U   175593  0.201741
6     None      I  9413116  0.432138
7     None      U   292982  0.336611
```

### Speed comparison

```
dfbig = pd.concat([df]*100000)
dfbig.shape

(800000, 4)
```

*Erfan 1*

```
%%timeit

dfbig['value2'] = dfbig['value'] / dfbig.groupby('groups')['value'].transform('sum')

109 ms ± 8.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*Erfan 2*

```
%%timeit

dfbig['value2'] = dfbig['value'].div(dfbig.groupby('groups')['value'].transform('sum'))

113 ms ± 2.96 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

*iamchoosinganame*

```
%%timeit

dfbig['value2']=dfbig.groupby('groups')['value'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())

412 ms ± 12.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using groupby and transform with a lambda function.

```
dataset['value2']=dataset.groupby('groups')['value'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())
```